# Gatsby on EC2 doesn't connect externally

Tags: amazon-ec2, gatsby

I have a development installation of Gatsby Doc site running on my EC2 server.

When I run the code on my dev machine it works and I can connect my browser to port 8000 and everything is ok..

On my server i check out my github code and

```
yarn install
npm run start.
```

Everything builds correctly and Gatsby it listening on port 8000

From my dev machine when I connect using

X.X.X.X:8000 in my browser i receive

> Unable to connect

I have opened the port on 8000 in the firewall and I have tested that it works as expected using:

```
nc -lv 8000
```

on the server (where gatsby is going to run) and connect using telnet.

on the server i receive

```
Listening on [0.0.0.0] (family 0, port 8000)
Connection from 84.232.Y.Y 38552 received!
```

So it works.

When Gatsby is finished starting i see

`You can now view gatsbyjs.org in the browser. ⠀ http://localhost:8000/` 
⠀
when i enter the web address and port i receive

`Unable to connect`

again. do I need to start Gatsby in another mode?

Kim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out.
I just added -H 0.0.0.0 to the start up command and everything works now.